# Why does subversion fail with message: "svn: E720003: Can't move ..." or "svn: E720003: Can't open ..."?

Tags: windows-7, svn

When doing svn export or svn checkout from the command line to a relative target directory I get the following error messages halfway through the checkout or export:

> svn: E720003: Can't move ...

or

> svn: E720003: Can't open ...

Why?

I'm using the command line version (svn.exe) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Answer by the OP posted as community wiki:</sub>

Stop using relative paths, always give svn.exe absolute paths.

I was using relative paths as checkout/export target with multiple levels of
 `..\..\`.

Comment: is there any other solution other than using absolute paths?

Comment: I have not stumbled upon any other solution.